# Dialog method does not work

Tags: android, methods, dialog, forceclose

I am trying to create a dialog method but when i call it, it causes a force close.  The only thing i get on my log cat is:

dalvikvm thread=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40ab5c08)

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPoinerExeption

im sure the rest is standard

**here is a snipped of my code:**

```
 Dialog PercentDialog;

 private void CreateDialog() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Context context = Home.this;
    PercentDialog = new Dialog(context);
    //PercentDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    PercentDialog.setContentView(R.layout.percent_box);
    Button bOK = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bOK);
    Button bCancel = (Button) PercentDialog.findViewById(R.id.bCancel); 
    EditText etInt = (EditText) PercentDialog.findViewById(R.id.etInt); 
    TextView title = (TextView) PercentDialog.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);   
    bOK.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    });
    bCancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            PercentDialog.dismiss();
        }

    });

    PercentDialog.show();
}
```

Then i use CreateDialog(); to call my method but it is forced closed.

Comment: You probably don't have those views at your layout.. Show us your `percent_box` layout code. Btw, the rest of the exception trace is not _standard_, it points out to exactly where the problem is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging from your existing code, this line:

```
Button bOK = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bOK);
```

Should be:

```
Button bOK = (Button) PercentDialog.findViewById(R.id.bOK);
```

(Also please read about [Java naming conventions](http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm) which state that variables should start with a lowercase letter.)

Comment: thanks, i think it was my careless error of not noticing that or perhaps a a simple close and open eclipse (since it fails to work properly sometimes). Either way thanks for that and the "java naming conventions" link